# Invalid syntax error with nbmerge function?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I cannot use nbmerge to merge my jupyter notebooks together.

pip install nbmerge works on its own.

My three files are named as shown in the code and in the same directory.

```
pip install nbmerge

​nbmerge a.ipynb b.ipynb c.ipynb > merged.ipynb
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-78-417f6ff7a54e>", line 1
    nbmerge a.ipynb b.ipynb c.ipynb > merged.ipynb
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: can you try the same command from the command line and in that same directory?

Answer (score 1):

These are shell commands. You need to execute these commands using ('!') mark.
Modify your code to:

```
​!nbmerge a.ipynb b.ipynb c.ipynb > merged.ipynb.
```

Or else you can use `nbmerge.merge_notebooks()` function.